# Need simple NTFS permissions setup example

Tags: permissions, ntfs

I have a fairly straightforward need to setup permissions on an NTFS filesystem using icacls.exe.  I hope that someone can give a complete cookbook solution.  I believe this example will provide a general solution that will go far to help others to use and benefit from NTFS permissions.

Situation:

Create a folder in the root of a disk, for example C:\example
Create a folder in the sample folder, for example C:\example\foo
Create a folder in the sample folder, for example C:\example\bar

1) I want a normal user to be able to read (and search) the example folder, but be prohibited from creating new folders or files there.

2) I want a normal user to be able to read, create and edit files, but not delete files in the foo folder.

3) I want a normal user to be able to create files in bar, but subsequently be unable to view their contents or modify them.  (they can view the filenames only)

I want the Administrators to have all privileges.

It would be helpful also to have a separate manager (group/id) who has privileges to view and modify the contents of the files in bar.

IMHO, this is not an uncommon scenario and a simple cookbook solution would go a long ways to getting people started on creating their own permissions schemes.

BONUS POINTS if you can explain the steps necessary without acronyms or jargon  (ie the bps is the apg that gets applied to the bgb when you click the brb)

I sincerely hope there exists a kind and generous soul who can render assistance.

Comment: To Assist G-Man, and others who would like to assist, I can enhance the question by saying that NTFS default permissions include a handful of identities, Administrators, SYSTEM, CREATOR OWNER, Users and Username.  The available settings for each of these are numerous and include Full control, Traverse folder / execute file, List folder / read data, Read Attributes ...  And then there is inheritance to consider.  These are grouped by icacls.exe into a series of approx 32 rights/grants.  The combinations required to achieve the desired results are not trivial.  Not an easy task.

Comment: I think I have most of this figured out, and I will post my own answer once I get some details resolved.  The ultimate fix involves creating a container in which to do my permissions settings.  Kinda like the base object in OOP, that does nothing but contain main().  I needed to create a folder (the container), then create my lowest level folder in this folder, then files and folders inside the subfolder.  It almost makes sense once you do it, but also wasteful because you end up with an additional folder in the path.